# update item in listview after click on button

Tags: android, button, android-adapter

Basically what I need is to update a value of a listview item to which you have clicked on the button.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_validacion_multiple, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        /*holder.row1 = (TableRow)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
        holder.row2 = (TableRow)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);*/
        holder.txtNombre = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        holder.txtAsiento = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAsiento);
        holder.txtTicket = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTicket);
        holder.txtNumero = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumero);
        holder.btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtNombre.setText("Nombre :"+rowItem.getNombre());
    holder.txtTicket.setText("Ticket :"+rowItem.getTicket());
    if (!rowItem.getAsiento().equals("") && !rowItem.getAsiento().equals("null") && rowItem.getAsiento() != null) {
        holder.txtAsiento.setText("Asiento :"+rowItem.getAsiento());
    }
    if (!rowItem.getNumero().equals("") && !rowItem.getNumero().equals("null") && rowItem.getNumero() != null) {
        holder.txtNumero.setText("Número :"+rowItem.getNumero());
    }
    if(rowItem.getValidado()==1){
        holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_big_alert);
        holder.btn.setText("");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.width = 50;
        params.height = 50;
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        holder.btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    }else{
        holder.btn.setTag(position);
        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
                RowItem item_click = getItem(position);
                Connection cn = new Connection();
                SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
                if(cn.isNetworkAvailable(parent.getContext())){

                }else{
                    BaseDeDatos nueva = new BaseDeDatos();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

I thought about making the call to `holder.btn` but this does not work because it is not in the same context, there is some way to edit this item?

Comment: Whats the error you got

Comment: @HassanUsman Within the onClick I can not handle the object to modify Holder.btn

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 int position= Integer.parseInt(v.getTag());
```

Hope this work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I need is to change the background of the button and can not get the item.

Comment: It does not solve my problem. How I can get the button on the item?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.